# BASH: simultaneous execution of a multiloop function without waiting

Tags: linux, bash

Usecase:

need to transfer binary files (1Gb) to array of IPs and start executing them upon arrival to their destinations without waiting all binaries to be transferred/executed. Sort of parallel mode.

Situation:

I have 2 functions - transfer and execution (depending on approach it can be shortened to 1 with 2 loops).

```
for N in "${NODES[@]}"; do
    rsync -Pcz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --timeout=10 $FILE user@$N
done
```

and

```
for N in "${NODES[@]}"; do
    ssh user@$N "cd ~/; ./exec.sh"
done
```

The point is that in this case i have to wait till all transfers finish first (and there sometimes can be tens of addresses)and just afterwards start the execution.

If i combine the loops into a single one, i have to wait again - this time for transfer+execution per node.

Expectation:

I'd like to transfer a file to the first node, start its execution, and switch to the second node with the same process, and so on. So timing would count for the transfers only, whereas each node executes the file on its own in parallel.

Obstacles:

1- need to be able to have an execution output from each node

2- additional packages, like **screen** are not an option.

What did i try:

i was thinking about injecting some script to the remote nodes via the loop to control the execution from there. But i'm sure there must be some less barbaric option.

What can be done here?

Comment: What about starting `rsync` in background (like `rsync ... &`) and wait for them after the `for` loop?

Comment: @Emily E. - not sure I understand what would be a benefit for the usecase. In a background or not I need to execute files upon finishing their transfer. Please elaborate.

Comment: Looks like an obvious use case for **GNU Parallel** which is no more than a Perl script itself. Are Perl scripts allowed in your environment - or only `bash`?

Comment: @Mark Setchell - Unfortunately bash only.

Comment: Are bash script with `--embed`ded perl script allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use a single loop, and run the `ssh` command with a `&` suffix, which runs it in the background (i.e. without waiting for it to finish), and then after the loop use `wait` to wait for all of them to finish. Collecting output will be more interesting... I think you'll need to collect each run's output into a file, and then print the files at the end. Something like this (note that I have **not** tested this properly):

```
tmpdir="$(mktemp -qd -t "$(basename "$0")")" || {
    echo "Error creating temporary directory" >&2
    exit 1
}

for nodenum in "${!NODES[@]}"; do
    # The ${!array[@]} idiom gets a list of array *indexes*, not elements; get the element by index:
    N=${NODES[nodenum]}
    # Copy file, and wait for copy to finish:
    rsync -Pcz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --timeout=10 $FILE user@$N
    # Start the script, and *don't* wait for it to finish:
    ssh user@$N "cd ~/ sh exec.sh" >"$tmpdir/$nodenum.out" 2>&1 &
done

# Wait for all of the scripts to finish
wait

# Print all of the outputs (in order)
for nodenum in "${!NODES[@]}"; do
    echo
    echo "Output from ${NODES[nodenum]}:"
    cat "$tmpdir/$nodenum.out"
done

# Clean up the temp directory
rm -R "$tmpdir"
```

BTW, the remote command `"cd ~/ sh exec.sh"` doesn't make sense. Is there supposed to be a semicolon in there? Also, I recommend using lower or mixed-case variable names to avoid conflicts with the many all-caps variables that have some sort of special meaning, and putting double-quotes around variable references (i.e. `rsync ... "$FILE" "user@$N"` instead of `rsync ... $FILE user@$N`).

EDIT: this assumes you want to start the script on each host as soon as that particular copy is done; if you want to wait until *all* copies are done, then fire all scripts at once, use two loops: one to do the copies, then a second that does the `ssh` commands in the background (collecting output as above), then wait for those to all finish, then print all of the outputs.

Comment: thank you. This sounds like something that has the right to live! :) I was thinking about something similar, but to be executed from the remote hosts' initiation. Will test during the day and update then.

And yes, there should be a semicolon. Edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the transfer and script as a single background task, so that the script on a particular host starts as soon as its transfer is complete

```
for N in "${NODES[@]}"; do
    (rsync -Pcz -e "ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null" --timeout=10 $FILE user@$N
     ssh user@$N "cd ~/; ./exec.sh") > ${N}.log 2>&1 &
done
```

You then collect all of the hostname.log files

Comment: This'll run all of the copies (`rsync` commands) at once, not just the scripts.

Comment: That was the plan - it means that the whole job only takes as long as the slowest machine. There will be a little contention on the local disk as several rsync commands try to read the same files, but caching will help.